# how do i filter through a CSV file and group the values without the use of any type of imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

My project requires me to have a main function called
`def main(csvfile,country,type):`

I am going to explain the project requirements so that I can understand how to begin this project. The project requires me to find minimum, maximum, standard deviation and correlation of the number of positive covid cases in EACH country for EACH month. In this case positive cases = new cases in the csvfile. The main function will be used to test the whole Python script  for checking the test cases. There is a complexity with TYPE as:

type is the input argument which mentions which type of analysis are required. It can take
only one of the two string inputs: “statistics” or “correlation”. If third input
argument is “statistics”, then the objective of the program is to find the statistical
analysis of a **single country**. Otherwise if the third input argument is “correlation” then
the objective of the program is to find the correlation of statistical data of **two countries**.

so far this is the code I have written :

```
def main(csvfile,country,type):
    try:
        Fileopen = open(csvfile,"r")                                                             #code opens the csv file 
        Fileread = Fileopen.read()
        Filelines = Fileread.split("\n")                                                          #splits the list with a new line
        listname = []
    
        for line in Filelines:
            Filevalues = line.split(",")                                                          #splits the  list with a comma 
            listname.append(Filevalues)
            
        for index in range (len(listname)):                                                       #loop checks and removes any empty lists from the csv
            if listname[index] == ['']:
                listname.pop(index)

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('please check if the name of the file is correct')
        quit()
```

Hence, I am confused on how to begin with filtering the csvfile with each country with the number of cases for each month and then finding the min/max and so on. Just need a little guide.

[How the csvfile looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jpWB.png)

Comment: you can use pandas library to read csv file and then you can filter pandas data frame as per requirement.

Comment: hi, my project requirement does not allow any imports of library:(

Comment: No import of any library, or no import of any *external* package? Can you use the built-in csv module?

Comment: You are not allowed to import any Python module. While use of the many of these modules,
e.g. csv or math is a perfectly sensible thing to do in a production setting, it takes away
much of the point of different aspects of the project, which is about getting practice opening
text files, processing text file data, and use of basic Python structures, in this case lists and
loops. This is what is listed in the project specification.

Comment: Looks like you've actually got the basics, stated in your above comment, done in this code. The whole correlation & statistics part just needlessly complicates that, in my opinion. Of course, that won't help you with the assignment, but it seems a bit silly.

Comment: You could use a dict with countries as keys, and store the dict value as a list, to start with. That could make the statistics part easier: you can easily pull out a list of values for a single country.

Comment: `type`, by the way, is a slightly bad name for a variable, since it overrides a built-in function (you can even see the StackOverflow markup has highlighted it, for that reason). If that is really the name of the function argument in the way you got it from the project, I'm not impressed by the project.

Comment: You can also simply skip the countries you don't need. If `country` is a single country, skip all other countries. If `country` is two countries (for the correlation statistic), use two lists to store the values of each country, skip over all other countries while iterating over the file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that extra loop that cleans data could be a simple line:

```
listname = [x for x in listname if x and x[0]]
```

The same way could be apply to your filter, let's say you wish to search a specific country "Albania". Knowing the index of your location column is "2" (third column) You could do it simply like this:

```
countryfilter = [x for x in listname if len(x) >= 2 and x[2] == "Albania"]
print(countryfilter)
```

Here're some examples to get some statistical insight on new cases:

```
new_cases = [int(x[4]) for x in countryfilter] 
new_cases.sort()
min_new_cases = new_cases[0]
max_new_cases = new_cases[-1]
average = sum(new_cases) / len(new_cases)
```